# Bluetooth project | Bluetooth transmitter connection to android mobile

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

Description: I want to create a Bluetooth transmitter that will pair with my android phone. I will send a ping(alert kind of notification) from my Bluetooth transmitter device(on a button press), and the android phone should receive it.

Questions

1. From where exactly should I start to create a product described
    above?
2. What should be the steps?
3. What Components should I have to accomplish the above?

Comment: This will probably be closed a "too broad".

Comment: How is this any different from your [other question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/113396/a-project-on-bluetooth-bluetooth-beginner-video-tutorials-of-basic-bluetooth)?

Comment: some people didnt leave the comment and had put my question on hold, so i had specifically put the new question, as I didnt get the satisfactory answer, I see that you are not providing any answer and commenting some irrelevant stuff here, but that's fine.
I finally found the exact thing i needed - which is 'RFDuino'.

Comment: @Bhrugs, did the answer by Haresh K below solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these are the components you require :

- Arduino uno
- bluetooth module
- Connection wires and power supply
- switch interfaced with the arduino (make sure you take care of the bouncing)
- laptop with eclipse and android sdk .
- android mobile with bluetooth enabled.

via serial communication ,code the arduino so as to transmit the bluetooth data of the switch position to the mobile. the android app you develop using eclipse ide will receive the data and display.

Stuff you need to learn to accomplih the task : Arduino language coding, Java programming for android app development (if that's hectic, try the mit app generator online) .

Hope i helped ! :)

Comment: RFDuino is better option for my requirement.

Comment: Do we need specific Bluetooth chip/module to be able to Android? Can we just simple use HC-05/HC-06 if we want to access Android, say like to control its volume, camera, etc?